# elasticsearch - how to filter query on property of an object

Tags: elasticsearch

In my doc, I have an **object with user-id's as properties**:

```
{
    name:"bill"
    connections:{
        352077: {
            id          :352077
            username    :john
            genre       :"M"
        }
        3472236: {
            id          :3472236
            username    :cris
            genre       :"F"
        }
        4967367: {
            id          :4967367
            username    :mary
            genre       :"F"
        }
    }
}
```

How can I perform a **query to get** only connections with **genre = "F"**?

To run an update query, this works well:

```
{script:"for(i:ctx._source['connections'].entrySet()){ i.value.genre = 'F'; }"}
```

But I don't know how to run as GET query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should restructure your documents like that

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/connection/bill_352077' -d '{
    "name":"bill",
    "id":352077,
    "username":"john",
    "genre":"M"      
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/connection/bill_3472236' -d '{
    "name":"bill",
    "id":3472236,
    "username":"cris",
    "genre":"F"    
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/connection/bill_4967367' -d '{
    "name":"bill",
    "id":4967367,
    "username":"mary",
    "genre":"F"     
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/connection/bob_12345' -d '{
    "name":"bob",
    "id":12345,
    "username":"rosie",
    "genre":"F"     
  }'

curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/connection/_search?q=genre:F%20AND%20name:bill'
```

If this is not an option maybe you can try a multi_search query

```
{
   "query":{
      "multi_match":{
         "query":"F",
         "fields":[
            "connections.*.genre"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

but thats not really working for your document structure because its not indented to search within documents and return only the parts the search match. https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/3022

Maybe you solve it via nested mapping, 
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html
but then you can access such documents only via nested queries and normally that is not that what you want.

Comment: re-structure to index each connection as a document is a option. I just don't really know advantages/disadvantages of doing this.

Comment: Thats like defining a database model. It depends on your use case. Maybe this helps: http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/what-is-an-elasticsearch-index/ and http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/your-data-your-search/ and https://www.found.no/foundation/elasticsearch-mapping-introduction/